# Can Python be used to send a true key down event to Mac

Tags: python, macos, applescript, keypress, keydown

My question is, is there any way to reliably hold a key down on a mac with applescript/python?

I have search almost everywhere for topics like this, however, none of them cut it. I am attempting to use Python to read serial information from an Arduino, then relay those signals as keypresses. I have seen how to use applescript to send a "key down" to the system event, as shown in the following code:

```
(Python code)
    def SendDown(key):
    string = str(key)
    cmd = """osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key down (key code """ + string   + ")'"
    os.system(cmd)
```

This code works generally, however, I want to control the Google flight simulator. When I attempt to do this, the key presses seem to be way to quick and the flight simulator or the basic google earth map moves fractions of what I would expect.

They way I am using this code is essentially as follows (suedocode)

```
if (ArduinoMessage == "left"):
    SendDown(leftKey) #leftKey has been set to 123 -- the code for the left arrow key
    etc...
```

From my point of view, the key down event I'm sending is essentially a quick keystroke and the key is not being held down. I tried programming the key event directly in applescript and had a little bit of success. My code looked something like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat 50 times    
        key down (key code 123)
    end repeat
    key up (key code 123)
end tell
```

That code moved the google earth map more than I have been getting, but it took a long time to get it to move a small amount (far less than the normal arrow keys). Then I tried to write that applescript into Python and lost all improvement.

So I restate the question -- is there any way to reliably hold a key down on a mac with applescript/python?

I was able to get this to work on Windows fairly easily, however, I was able to use a Windows only library called SendKeys that is designed for applications such as this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: Great name in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput).
Try following code.

```
import time

import pykeyboard


# TODO: Replace following two lines with the code that activate the application.
print('Activate the application 3 seconds.')
time.sleep(3)

k = pykeyboard.PyKeyboard()
k.press_key(k.left_key)
time.sleep(1) # Hold down left key for 1 second.
k.release_key(k.left_key)
```

Unfortunately I don't have Mac. I tested in Linux, Windows.

Comment: Good suggestion falsetru, turns out it does not work on Mac. Apparently the pykeyboard is only Windows and Linux. (See [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUserInput/0.1)) However, I was able to get a suggestion from them -- [autopy](http://msanders.github.io/autopy/), which may work on Mac. So your suggestion is not in vain. Thank you.

Comment: I've been looking into autopy and many people can't get it to install on Mac, also xcode is a required download. I would like my application to be a quick install -- since xcode is nearly 2gb this doesn't seem very useful. Hopefully someone another method exists.

Comment: @Jake, How about using PyMouse (which is included in PyUserInput). Using PyMouse will require some calculation, but no need to sleep.

Comment: @Jake, Alternative is use `delay` in applescript (I think it will be similar to time.sleep in Python) as in my answer code.

Comment: @Jake, There is another option: [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). It requires you to install Java.

Comment: I really like Sikuli, it works well, however, seems a bit bulky. I did take your advice on using delays in applescript. It turns out that pure applescript works correctly. I believe what was happening is that when I tell applescript through Python to key down, since the tell ends immediately after that, I believe in essence, the key up was being sent immediately after the key down. I believe with multi-threading in python, I can implement something that runs a large piece of applescript that actually delays. I'll post the finished code soon (if it works). Thank you for all your help!